# H & R Block did my taxes, and I don't believe the results

Tags: taxes

I had my taxes prepared by H & R BLOCK. I have for three years. Their payment would always come from my refund.

This year I owe taxes, $1300, and there has to be some type of mistake.

I want to get my tax forms back from them --just my original forms, not any work or figures from them, so I can do it myself.

Am I obligated to pay for their service?

Comment: Please  don't write in all capital letters; it's painful to read and "sounds" like you are shouting at us.

Comment: Why do you assume there must be a mistake?  Are the numbers on the tax form they filled out right?

Comment: Fixed the orthography.

Comment: Do you want your forms from this year or last few years?  Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 7):

If they did any work at your request, then yes, you are obligated to pay for that work even if you decide not to use it.

If you can show that they made a mistake, they probably have some sort of guarantee. Ask them, and/or read the paperwork you signed and were given when you asked them to prepare your taxes.

To get your "original forms back", again just ask them. Better, since you're paying for it anyway, get the whole package from them and compare it to the results you get. That may show you where the mistake was, and whether it's theirs... or yours.

Good luck.

Comment: There are some companies that will review tax forms filled out by other companies and only make you pay if they can save you money. Using H+R Block's guarantee, you should be able to get your money back if the other company legitimately computes lower taxes.